# Pasar datos de un array multidimensional a un array unidimensional

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente array multidimensional el cual quiero ordenar en dos diferentes campo, es decir, un arreglo **carro** y un arreglo **modelo** el cual contengan los ejemplos que les asigne:

```
$arreglo = array(
        array("Carro" => "BMW", "Modelo" => "M3"),
        array("Carro" => "Mercedes", "Modelo" => "Benz"),
        array("Carro" => "Ferrari", "Modelo" => "LaFerrari"),
        array("Carro" => "Pagani", "Modelo" => "")
    );

    var_dump($arreglo);
```

No se si me doy a explicar.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Si nos muestras tu progreso tendremos un punto de partida desde el que poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para dividir un array en dos basta con recorrer el array padre con un foreach y asignar los valores deseados a tus nuevos arreglos de la siguiente manera:

```
$arreglo = array(
    array("Carro" => "BMW", "Modelo" => "M3"),
    array("Carro" => "Mercedes", "Modelo" => "Benz"),
    array("Carro" => "Ferrari", "Modelo" => "LaFerrari"),
    array("Carro" => "Pagani", "Modelo" => "")
);

$carro = [];
$modelo = [];

foreach($arreglo as $a){
    array_push($carro, $a['Carro']);
    array_push($modelo, $a['Modelo']);
}
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!